# Generating a number or string that has not been generated before?

Tags: python, random

I am creating a black jack inspired game and i generate the deck and hand using the following code:

```
suits = 'SCHD'
values = '23456789TJQKA'

deck = tuple(''.join(card) for card in itertools.product(values, suits))

dealershand = random.sample(deck, 1)
yourhand    = random.sample(deck, 2)
```

The problem with this is that there is a small chance that the same card is pulled in the 'dealershand' and 'yourhand' I would like to check if the card already exists, and if it does, to generate another card. Something like this:

```
while yourhand is in dealershand:
    yourhand=random.sample(deck,2)
```

Comment: It's pretty traditional when playing card games that when you deal a card to one player, you *remove that card from the deck* before dealing the next. In other words, a deck of cards should be represented as a structure from which you remove cards, not just choose them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a way to make it safely:

```
from itertools import product
from random import sample
suits = 'SCHD'
values = '23456789TJQKA'

deck = tuple(''.join(card) for card in product(values, suits))

dealershand = sample(deck, 1)
yourhand    = sample(tuple([x for x in deck if x not in dealershand]), 2)
```

Comment: That's just a band-aid on a fundamentally flawed approach. Dealing a card in the real world means not only assigning it to a player, but physically removing it from the deck and moving it into the player's hand. These actions should be simulated by removing the card objects from the deck collection and adding it to the hand collection.

Answer (score 10):

You can use `random.shuffle(deck)` to shuffle the deck (which needs to be a `list` rather than a `tuple`) and then you can use `deck.pop()` to draw one card at the time.

Comment: How  would i convert mine into a list?

Comment: You can create it as a list in the first place: `deck = [''.join(card) for card in itertools.product(values, suits)]` or convert your current tuple into a list using `deck = list(deck)`.

Comment: By the way, you can also create the "Cartesian product" list directly without using itertools: `deck = [value + suit for value in values for suit in suits]`.